# iOS 8 Swift - ScrollViewer and Autolayout content out of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to make a scroll view on iOS with Swift and Autolayout, but the screen crop the content instead of resizing it.

[image]

My layout and constraints
[image]

How can i fix this ?

EDIT : Tried with UITextView it doesn't work too

EDIT 2 : I'm trying to make a screen [like that](http://goo.gl/s9jdKH) and my problem is that i can't implements this screen for all screens resolution and rotation with AutoLayout

Comment: I am confused with what you are trying to do.  Scrollview purpose is to crop its contentView, allowing you to move the screen to view the whole content.  Could elaborate what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make a simple vertical ScrollView like Android ScrollView or XAML ScrollViewer and a TextBlock with TextWrapping property setted to Wrap, all elements setted to fill width take the screen size and if TextView are bigger than screen width, it grow on height to show all text by adding new line.

Comment: My label is setted to maxLines 0 and wrapping to characters wrap

Comment: For what you are describing it sounds like a [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html) will work better.

Comment: (Replaced image in question) it doesn't work too

Comment: Are you still using a scrollView?  If so you don't too.  Are you building you auto layout in code or interface builder?

Comment: I'm still using a ScrollView because i need to add more items in this view (ImageView and another Textview). I'm building with interface builder.
I forgot to mention that i'm using XCode 6.1

Comment: With what you are describing I would lean more towards a UItableView and have each cell be the individual item you want to display.  But with than said, I am going to think out loud about how I would tackle this problem.  First I would want the scroll view to fill on controller view and have the scrollView contentView fill the scroll view window. This [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) talks about it; it is in objective-c but it applies to swift as well.  Then you would need to add constraint for each object inside of the scroll view.

Comment: It doesn't work too. Is it really impossible (or very hard) to make a simple screen like this http://goo.gl/s9jdKH (title text, image and content text with vertical scroll) on iOS for all screen size ? On Android or Windows Phone this is really easy and this is not a complex screen, i don't understand why it is so hard on iOS

Comment: I retried the Apple article, i got "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." , i tried with and without constraint in Interface Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution !

Use Interface Builder only to add a UIScrollView and add constraints to fit superview, and create all subviews programatically.

Override `updateViewConstraints()`and for each view in the ScrollView set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false and add a width constraint to keep scrollview width. Dont forget to call super.updateViewConstraint().

Override `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation()` and `viewDidAppear()` and set `scrollView.contentSize.height` to wrap all items (if you don't do that, you can't scroll).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var constraintsUpdated = false;
    var label = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        scrollView.addSubview(label)
    }

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        if(constraintsUpdated){
            //Rotate, just update view and keep constraints
            super.updateViewConstraints()
            scrollView.layoutSubviews()
            return;
        }

        var viewsDictionary = ["label": label, "scrollView": scrollView]
        let screenWidth = self.view.frame.width

        label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(String(format: "H:[label(==scrollView)]", screenWidth), options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

        constraintsUpdated = true
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        //Update subviews
        scrollView.layoutSubviews()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    scrollView.contentSize.height = label.bounds.height
}

    override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        scrollView.contentSize.height = label.bounds.height
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I found another solution with [FLKAutoLayout](https://github.com/floriankugler/FLKAutoLayout) library, that's work great with less code!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var labelTitle: UILabel = UILabel()

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //TITLE
        scrollView.addSubview(labelTitle)

        labelTitle.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        labelTitle.numberOfLines = 0

        //constraints
        labelTitle.constrainWidthToView(self.view, predicate: nil)
        labelTitle.numberOfLines = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        scrollView.contentSize.height = labelTitle.frame.height
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's a UIScrollView bug with AutoLayout or a feature